# How to detect referring page url in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, browser-history

In a page, I redirect user to an external link using `router.push('destination-url')`.

I need to check if the user has clicked back from the page that I already redirected them to or not.
If the user is coming form an external link, they must not visit this page again (preventing duplicate redirect to the same destination).

**In other words**: I need to redirect the user to an external link only if they came from an specific internal page.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (window) {
    if (router.isReady) {

      // --- HERE I NEED TO CHECK IF USER CLICKED BACK FROM THE EXTERNAL URL THAT I ALREADY REDIRECTED THEM TO ---

      getLinkAddress({id: router.query.id, price: router.query.price}).then((r1) => {
        if (r1.link_address) {
          setFound(true);
          router.push(r1.link_address).then();
        } else {
          setFound(false);

          setTimeout(() => {
            router.back();
          }, 3000);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return () => { };
}, [router.query]);
```

Comment: you can use the document.referrer property to check the previous page's URL and determine if it matches your specific internal page

Comment: @Baki - It's always the same, it doesn't change if user clicks BACK from the external url that I've already redirected them to.

Comment: you can set a flag in the browser's session storage or a cookie when you redirect the user to the external link. Then when the user navigates back to the page you can check for the presence of this flag and avoid the redirect

Comment: @Baki - That's a good idea. I'll wait for a nextjs built-in solution, if I couldn't find one, I go with your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (window && router.isReady) {

    const redirectedFlag = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectedFlag');

    if (!redirectedFlag) {

      getLinkAddress({ id: router.query.id, price: router.query.price }).then((r1) => {
        if (r1.link_address) {
          setFound(true);

          sessionStorage.setItem('redirectedFlag', 'true');

          router.push(r1.link_address).then();
        } else {
          setFound(false);

          setTimeout(() => {
            router.back();
          }, 3000);
        }
      });

    } else {
      console.log("User is coming back from the external link");
    }
  }

  return () => { };
}, [router.query]);
```